# Play Local MP3's with PHP

Tags: php, directory, mp3, local

I am trying to build an mp3 player through PHP. So far I made it like this:
http://dataonrequest.com/mp3player/

Now I want to make it in a way to play local files. Instead of getting the directory list from your host folders, I want it to get the dir from a local chosen Folder and build up the library with php just like my online example. e.g. (C:\Music)

Comment: Ummmmm....no.  PHP does **server-side processing**.  The MP3s are on the **client**'s system.  You'll need more than PHP to do this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to play ***my own MP3's*** on *my computer*, or something else? If you want it to play local files, you will need to make a browser add-on, and probably forgo the server-side stuff.

Comment: Yes I want it to play local computer files, just like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AKCYx/

Comment: But I gues PHP gives you the possibility to search in directories,  that's why I wanted to use php tech

Comment: @nouky - PHP is going to be running on the server though, so it will only be able to search directories on the server.

Comment: @Brendan isn't there a way to use PHP to browse and display directories of your local pc in a browser?? Or is that possible only with Desktop App?

Comment: @nouky - As the others have said, PHP is just server side ...

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to stream your MP3s to anyone and everyone on the internet, much less let everyone on the internet **browse through the file system on your server**?!

Comment: @nouky - No. PHP runs on the server. Users can upload their music to your server, but you can read their local filesystem because your PHP program doesn't have access to it.

Comment: My idea was to build an app that annyone can use for his personal use. For example I can run this app locally and gain access to all those mp3's and it would work fine. But I wanted the App to be available for not only me, that's why I tried to make it work through an online server

Comment: The App would be just a substitution for Windows Media Player

Comment: Tnx for all the replies, I guess I'll just make it locally...

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at Javascript and something like jQuery and jPlayer (http://jplayer.org/) and jQuery.twFile.

Though if I found a website that was automatically reading my local file system and I'd get really, really upset.  And it's not a great idea to just setup file browsing on your server for anything to break into.